# static variable declaration and definition in C++

Tags: c++, static

I have a sample code as shown below:

```
 class myclass
{
public:
    static int j;
    myclass(){};
    ~myclass(){};
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    myclass obj;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now I have declared a static int inside myclass and although I have not defined it, the compiler does not give me any errors until I began using the static variable. Why is that?

Comment: You only need a definition if you odr-use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these are linker errors, not compiler errors. Linker errors never arise until you use an undefined symbol.

Answer (score 2):

> *"the compiler does not give me any errors until I began using the static variable. Why is that?"*

Because it didn't need to be linked with your code until that point (when you start to use it). Unused code is ignored / stripped off by the linker.

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with the linker discarding unused symbols' definitions.